# Exception reading Manifest with OneDrive

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am trying to publish a generic WinForm application using OneDrive from Visual Studio 2022 (just a form with a button). I set Publish Location to a folder on Onedrive, and then I share the OneDrive directory to extract the URL, and use that for the Install Location. Visual Studio writes the files out fine, and even creates an .html file for installation, but when I click Install, it gives me an error saying the Manifest is bad. Here is the output

[image]

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 10.0.22621.0 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
clr.dll             : 4.8.9075.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
dfdll.dll           : 4.8.9032.0 built by: NET481REL1
dfshim.dll          : 10.0.22621.30000 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnxJ9sdoqHuhhbUD2vlxEO-N65DIEw?e=TeFxXK/Form1.application

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnxJ9sdoqHuhhbUD2vlxEO-N65DIEw?e=TeFxXK/Form1.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
+ Exception reading manifest from https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A17BA868C7F6497C!88707&authkey=!ANr5cRDvjeuQyBM&e=TeFxXK%2fForm1.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
+ Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed:
-HRESULT:   0x8007001f
Start line:    0
Start column:  0
Host file:
+ A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [12/31/2022 3:52:55 PM] : Activation of https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnxJ9sdoqHuhhbUD2vlxEO-N65DIEw?e=TeFxXK/Form1.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [12/31/2022 3:52:55 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
- Exception reading manifest from https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A17BA868C7F6497C!88707&authkey=!ANr5cRDvjeuQyBM&e=TeFxXK%2fForm1.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
--- Inner Exception ---
System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
- Parsing and DOM creation of the manifest resulted in error. Following parsing errors were noticed:
-HRESULT:   0x8007001f
Start line:    0
Start column:  0
Host file:
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)
at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(FileStream fileStream)
at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
--- Inner Exception ---
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
- A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
- Source: System.Deployment
- Stack trace:
at System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.IsolationInterop.CreateCMSFromXml(Byte[] buffer, UInt32 bufferSize, IManifestParseErrorCallback Callback, Guid& riid)
at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadCMSFromStream(Stream stream)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.

So my question is: Should I be providing a URL to my OneDrive folder in a different way, other than Sharing it (to get a URL link)? I cannot seem to find any permission issues with the files in that folder using the URL link, but it complains.
So far I have tried different .NET versions, different manifest files, I reset Visual Studio, I uninstalled it and reinstalled it, then uninstalled it and installed a previous version (2019). Everything fails with this same error.

I am using Visual Studio 2022 on Windows 11 computer, if that matters.

Thoughts on what the issue may be? Should I avoid OneDrive for this? Maybe there is a better option?

Thank you.

Comment: possibly antivirus? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/115910/how-to-fix-0x8007001f-on-windows-10.html

Comment: I tried disabling anti-virus, but same error. Looking at the link, it mentions changing a Kernel setting, but that option is not showing in the list for me, so that may be something Pro offers, and Home does not (or something). Also, I failed to note, that if I double click Form1.Application, it installs and runs normally, but the Setup.exe and the Publish.html/Install options both produce the same error as above.